# Android folder monitor

Tags: android

Am using sdcard for saving data ,my problem is that when app is running and  some one delete this folder then the application fail. Is there anyway to notify the app , when this folder get deleted ?. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```
 private static File logFile = null;
    String SD_CARD_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    logFile = new File(SD_CARD_PATH + "/" + "folderName");
    if (logFile.exists()){
       //exist.so do your work
    }
    else{
      //not exists
    }
```